# JavaFX: Button(s) in HBox with same width

Tags: java, javafx

I have a HBox and two (or more) Button's in it. And I want all the buttons be of the same width. I can't set width of the buttons in pixels because texts are taken from resource bundle for every language (so length of the text is variable). This is the code I tried, but didn't succeed:

```
Button but1=new Button("Long text");
Button but2=new Button ("Text");
HBox.setHgrow(but1, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(but2, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox hbox=new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(but1,but2);
Scene scene=new Scene(hbox, 1000, 600);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha if we say "same width" then it is supposed that there are at least two buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set button maximum width to maximum value:

```
but1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

But it will only resize buttons to fill hbox width. If you need buttons with the same width, you should find the longest button and then set its width to other buttons.

```
but1.setPrefWidth(width);
```

Comment: But "find the longest button" is not particularly easy... you need to make sure a layout pass has been made, etc. And the width of the longest button might change if the width of the `HBox` changes.

Comment: I agree it's not easy to define button width in this situation. I haven't tested it. Perhaps you should create custom HBox to have control of layout childeren, but this is a lot of work and not scope of current question.

Comment: It is also possible to just set pref and min width to the same value. Then the length of the text is no longer relevant for the layouting. This might not be what the original question asked for since the text might be clipped but it can work cases where is is not a relevant.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the `maxWidth` of the Button to `Double.MAX_VALUE` and also set `HBox.setHgrow()` to `Priority.ALWAYS` to make the  Button fill the available width in the HBox.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button but1 = new Button("Long text");
        Button but2 = new Button ("Text");
        HBox hbox=new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(but1,but2);

        but1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        but2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(but1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(but2, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene=new Scene(hbox, 1000, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer - works perfectly! May be button-attribute settings work as expected after adding those into the `HBox`(?).